# which is better to use Data feed or Google Content API (Google merchant)

Tags: magento-1.8, mage-googleshopping

I have a store with over 20K+ product out of which i have listed around 15K product to Google shopping using Magento Google shopping extension that makes use of Google content API.

I also need to import inventory changes on daily basis which i do it using Magmi.

I am not sure, if this product are synced with Google merchant on real time, due to which i am facing issue. Few product which are out of stock are still showing as in stock on Google Shopping.

I always run the data Synchronization process, but thats a very time consuming job and takes hours to finish.

Can any one please guide me how i can do a real time sync with Google merchant.

And, Is using Magmi a good option for importing data on daily basis?

Your feedback can help me a lot.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer 1: Which is better: Feed or API**
Data Feed and Content API, both have their PROS and CONS

For 20k products, I would suggest that you stick to XML feed and here is why:
Google keeps on changing the specifications of its content requirements and its easier to maintain XML feed while its difficult to comply with that in API.

If you are looking to actively maintain the store and keep it abreast with Google's ever changing policies, forget about using any plugin available and get prepared to make changes on your own.

As of now, no plugin on Magento plugin store is up to date with all Google Merchant's policies.

**Best way to import data:**
In my opinion, Make a data parser and inject the data into Magento directly than doing it manually everyday using Magmi. Though, it needs through testing. I implemented it for certain clients and it needs to be done very carefully.

**For Realtime Data sync**
There is nothing called realtime data sync (unless you are using content API) in XML and minimum time is 1 day, which is okay. Set Google to load the feed on daily basis and update the same. Inventory data gets updated that way on daily basis.